# deployd - post method to retrieve object

Tags: deployd

Trying to use deployd.com framework for simulating a backend service. I am fairly new to deployd, appreciate any example or pointer in the right direction. Trying to retrieve an object using POST method. It looks like POST is used to create objects.

In my case, POST data contains a few query fields that will be used to query an object and send json back. Is this possible using deployd by modifying onPost method or some other way?
I cannot use GET with query parms due to security restrictions.

here is post request data

[
{
customer:"sam",
city:"noWhere",
}
]

the POST event should query by customer and city, then return matching customer object

[
{
customer:"sam",
postcode:"352345",
city:"noWhere",
country:"US"
}
]